# What is the meaning of the square brackets in ant colony optimization?

Tags: papers, swarm-intelligence, notation, ant-colony-optimization

I'm studying the paper "[Minimizing Total Tardiness on a Single Machine Using Ant Colony Optimization](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/f1b8/afdbf9f108afdb42476850ed3fc13db43cea.pdf)" which has proposed to use Ant colony optimization to SMTWTP.

According to this paper:

> Each artificial ant iteratively and independently decides which job to
> append to the sub-sequence generated so far until all jobs are
> scheduled, Each ant generates a complete solution by selecting a job $j$
> to be on the $i$-th position of the sequence. This selection process is
> influenced through problem-specific heuristic information called
> visibility and denoted by $\eta_{ij}$ as well as pheromone trails denoted by $\tau_{ij}$. The former is an indicator of how good the choice of that job
> seems to be and the latter indicates how good the choice of that job
> was in former runs. Both matrices are only two dimensional as a
> consequence of the reduction in complexity

They have proposed this formula for the probability that job $j$ be selected to be processed on position $i$ (page 9 of the linked paper):

$$
\mathcal{P}_{i j}=\left\{\begin{array}{cl}
\frac{\left[\tau_{i j}\right]^{\alpha}\left[\eta_{i j}\right]^{\beta}}{\sum_{h \in \Omega}\left[\tau_{i h}\right]^{\alpha}\left[\eta_{i h}\right]^{\beta}} & \text { if } j \in \Omega \\
0 & \text { otherwise }
\end{array}\right.\tag{1}\label{1}
$$

but I can't understand what $[]$ surrounding $\eta_{ij}$ and $\tau_{ij}$ indicates. Does it show that these values are matrices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The square brackets $[]$ in $[\tau_{ij}]^\alpha$ and $[\eta_{ij}]^\beta$ may be just a way of emphasing that the elements $\tau_{ij} \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\eta_{ij} \in \mathbb{R}$ of respectively the matrices $\mathbf{\tau} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ and $\mathbf{\eta} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ (where $n$ is the number of nodes in the graph) are respectively raised to $\alpha$ and $\beta$, so they could have used also other type of brackets, for example, $()$. It may also be a way of indicating that $[\tau_{ij}]$ and $[\eta_{ij}]$ are $1 \times 1$ matrices or vectors that contain respectively the scalars $\tau_{ij}$ and $\eta_{ij}$, so you are multiplying matrices or vectors (dot product).

This notation is also used in the paper that introduced the *ant colony system* (ACS) (and it is probably used in many other papers related to ant colony optimization). See equation 1 of [Ant Colony System: A Cooperative Learning Approach to the Traveling Salesman Problem](http://people.idsia.ch/~luca/acs-ec97.pdf) (1997) by Dorigo and Gambardella.

Comment: By the way, in the past, I've implemented the ant colony system (ACS). I've looked at my implementation and it seems to be consistent with my explanations above.